# Unable to Dial modem using LAN cable

Tags: wireless-router, modem, bridge, dial-up

I have a modem router , `D-Link DSL-2520U`, which has an ADSL cable. The modem router is connected to a Wireless Router `TP-LINK TL-WR740N` using a LAN cable. My devices connect wirelessly to the TP-LINK.

This setup works fine when I set the PPPoE mode in my modem. But I want to dial from my TP-LINK using bridge mode I get a timeout if I enable bridge mode and try connecting using the LAN cable (after inputting the credentials, of course). But I am able to dial using the USB port in the router modem. So the bridge mode works fine if I connect using USB, but it doesn't work if I connect using LAN from my PC (bypassed the router and tried directly connecting too).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This question is confusing because you don't "dial" an ADSL modem. You can possible bring the PPPoE or PPPoA session up or down, but you don't dial it. Also, you have an ADSL modem/router and a wireless router, but several times you just say "the router" without specifying which router you're talking about. Please rewrite your question to be more clear about these things.

Comment: when i go to windows , and set up a connection, there is an option to set up **Broadband (using PPPOE)**. What type of connection is that ?.
I have made some edits, please see to it

Comment: That's a PPPoE connection. You're doing PPP over Ethernet over DSL. You're not dialing an analog POTS modem.

Comment: okay, are you now able to understand my problem ?

Comment: No. What does "dial from my TP-LINK using bridge mode" mean? Is your TP-LINK set up as a PPPoE client, or is it set up in bridge mode, and you've got a Windows machine behind it that's doing PPPoE? When you say "connecting the LAN cable", exactly which two devices are you connecting via that LAN cable?

Comment: okay, for a TEST, i connected my PC to my modem using LAN. Then I set up that **Broadband(using PPPOE)** on my windows machine, and entered my user/pass. it did NOT connect. However, if i do the same thing by using the USB port, it connects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15648/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-spiff).